# Database with CSV's

Tags: mysql, csv

Hi guys I'm currently trying to create a database for a business which works with unit sensor data. A company has multiple monitoring units which has multiple sensors, each sensor spits out CSV files every hour or so.

Im trying to relate this data to a company, so clients can view their sensors when they enter the site. Im currently just importing csv scripts into custom tables (by custom i mean just custom headers), obviously the table can only be as big as the CSV table (needs to be the same amount of rows). But the issue i am having is trying to link the csv data to the company? The CSV's don't have id numbers so i cant use keys to link tables.

Here is my Schema: https://puu.sh/wRnPs/eff7a60b5b.png

Here is a CSV example: https://puu.sh/wRoPA/09b3146d40.png

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated i have done a lot of research and can't seem to find a solution!

Comment: If you know the company where the data comes from, could you not query the company's name to get the CustomerID ?  Then that ID could be the foreign key in the CSV table, perhaps?

Comment: If that ID was used in the table it would just have the foreign key ID listed in every row when the table is populated though? Meaning the ID would stay the same for every row?

Comment: But not if you get the ID **per company name**?  ... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: How would you present that ID in the CSV table though :/ ?

Comment: How is the data being imported/loaded to the CSV table ... `LOAD DATA`, or some other handling? ... and is it automated somehow (i.e. by scripts), or does someone load it manually?

Comment: The data is being imported via a cron job which automatically loads the CSV into the correct table.

Comment: Ok. First are there any other columns not shown in the CSV image?  Curious if there might be a RTU_ID, which can be just as useful as the CustomerID. Without either one of those ID's how do you know what CSV rows belong to a certain company?

Comment: No thats all of the columns. Thats exactly my problem Paul, there is no identification in any of the CSV's which is why I'm having so much trouble associating them.. ahah.

Comment: Do the file name's, in some way, have information that might include the RTU or customer name info?

Comment: Yes they can be named to suit the RTU or company!

Comment: "Can be", or are they already named this way?

Comment: By default they are named to the RTU Unit _ Sensor which is for instance RDOC332_Water. But we can rename the sensor save output as "company_Water".

Comment: Ok, I believe that you see my "general idea". There needs to be a **consistent** way to derive either the CustomerName or the RTU_ID. (The CustomerID may be easier, but I'm not sure, since I don't know what the RTU_ID looks like) Though I don't have the full picture, this could be the way to get the CustomerID to the CSV table, but the handling for whatever the `cron` is doing which I assume is doing a `LOAD DATA` type of operation and other associated matters will need updating to have all this working. If you're working with others, perhaps together, you can brainstorm the idea.

Comment: (continued) ... but if there may be other factors, post a comment later for other matters that might arise.

Comment: Hi Paul okay so i found a way to get the linking working basically by putting the sensor its self into a table and assigning a unique id for the whole table , populating every line. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Great! That sounds like good news, and hope it works moving forward.